# PostgreSQL: removing specific key of each elements in JSONB array

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I am having a table where one column is a JSONB column that has the following payload:

```
[
  {a: "foo", b: "bar"},
  {a: "bar", b: "baz"}
]
```

I want to remove the "b" element for each array item:

```
SELECT json_build_object(
  'id', s.id,
  'key', json_build_object(
    'key', s.column #- '{1, b}'
  )
) FROM table s
```

This works well but it removes it only from the second element of the array. I would like to remove it for every element of the array (the number of items in the array is not known and cannot be hardcoded.

Is there a way to do that easily?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unnest the `jsonb` array, subtract the key, and reaggregate:

```
select t.id, jsonb_agg(e.j - 'b' order by e.n) as some_jsonb
  from some_table t
       cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.some_jsonb) 
         with ordinality as e(j, n)
 group by t.id
;
```

Working [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ij-VHCeT)

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! I was thinking there could be something simpler!

Answer (score 1):

Try this `jsonb_agg` function by combining it with lateral join.

```
SELECT
  json_build_object(
    'id', s.id,
    'key', jsonb_agg(j.item - 'b')
  ) AS result
FROM table s

CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(s.your_jsonb_column) AS j(item)
GROUP BY s.id;
```

Also replace `your_jsonb_column` with the name of JSONB column that contains the array.
Hope it works.